# Construct a countably infinite subset A of $\mathbb{R}$ such that sup($A$)$\in A$ and inf($A$)$\notin A$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A=(x_n)$ be a decreasing sequence such that $x_k = 10^{-(k-1)}$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Then sup($A$)$=1 \in A$ and inf($A$)$=0\notin A$.

I'm provided a hint to construct the sequence as a union of two sequences $(a_{2n})$,$(a_{2n+1})$. I could make the evens converge to its supremum and the odds its infimum, but isn't constructing a single sequence as i did above more straightforward?

Comment: The sequence that you mentioned works indeed.

Comment: Maybe it was a typo, and the union of two sequences hint was intended for the version of the question where neither the sup or inf are in the set?

Comment: @Chessanator I think that's it. The question that follows this one asks for sup equal $+\infty$ and inf equal zero where $0\notin A$, then says to refer to the hint of the previous question.

Comment: Consider $A=\mathbb{Q} \cap(0,1]$ then $\sup A=1\in A, \inf A=0\notin A$

Answer (score 3):

Another example of such a set is $\{1/n : n = 1,2,3,\dots\}$.

Answer (score 2):

That is a very good answer.

You can also consider something like the set of rational numbers in the interval $(\sqrt 2,5]$